# Interval of convergence of the power series representation of $\int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t^4}dt$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find the interval of convergence of $\int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t^4}dt$.

Since $$\int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t^4}dt=\int_0^x \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-t^4)^ndt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^xt^{4n}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1},$$
apply the ratio test:$|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{4n+5}}{4n+5}}{(-1)^n\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}}|=|\frac{4n+1}{4n+5}x^4|\to|x^4|<1\iff |x|<1$

And at the end points $x=1,-1$, we have the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{4n+1}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{-1}{4n+1}$, and both are convergent by the Leibniz's criterion. Hence the interval of convergence is $[-1,1]$.

Is my answer correct? I don't know if I can use $|x^4|<1 \iff |x|<1$, since $|x^4|$ is a limit.

Comment: $\int_0^x\frac1{1+t^4}~\mathrm dt$ converges for all $x\in\mathbb R$.  Presumably, you meant to ask for the interval of convergence for the series expansion of $\int_0^x\frac1{1+t^4}~\mathrm dt$ centered at $x=0$?

Comment: $|x^4|<1\iff|x|<1$ is correct.  Easily proven assuming $x>0$, then $x<0$, then $x=0$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt yes, I guess. I was just asked to find the interval of convergence, and it was the part of the class of power series.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt if it converges for all $x$, then does it have a whole real line as the interval of convergence?

Comment: Then I suppose you'd like to make that clear to avoid answers that do not answer the question

Comment: The integral converges for all $x$, but the Maclaurin/Taylor/power series does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That integral converges for all $x$, so I guess you mean the *series* for that function.  If so, then the integral has the same radius of convergence as the series for the integrand, which can be found by geometric series.  It's the sum of $$1-t^4+t^8 - t^{12} +\cdots$$ with common ration $r=1$.  So that's an easier way than your use of the ratio test, but you still get the right answer.

For the endpoints, which is your real question, your work is fine and you have the correct answer.

Comment: you mean $1-t^4+t^8-t^{12}+...$?